# WPF, Displaying Emgu Image, using Binding

Tags: wpf, design-patterns, binding, emgucv

I am familiar with basic code to display an Emgu image in a WPF image box, when all the source code is in the MainWindow.xaml.cs code-behind.

However I am trying to place my Emgu-related code, including the "ProcessFrame" event / Queryframe snippet, into a separate class of static methods so that I can reuse them later. I am doing this because while I will want to be able to grab images from the same camera at a later stage, I also want the flexibility to display those images in a different image box. I am having trouble with this step.

If I could bind the Image box dynamically to a property in the static method (and also enable / disable that binding programmatically), I think that would solve my problem. However, there may be some other problem with the approach I am trying to take. Any code / xaml modifications greatly appreciated.

The following code works, but is unsatisfactory because it forces me to bundle ProcessFrame method into the MainWindow code:

XAML (working):

```
<Window x:Class="EmguWPF_Test.MainWindow"
     xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
     xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
     Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
     <Grid>
       <Image Height="215" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="62,66,0,0" Name="image1" Stretch="Fill" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="224"  />
     </Grid>
</Window>
```

MainWindow Code Snippet (working):

```
//using statements etc
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
private Image<Bgr, Byte> image; 
private Capture capture = null;

private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    InitializeCameras();
    timer = new DispatcherTimer();
    timer.Tick+=new EventHandler(ProcessFrame);
    timer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 10);
    timer.Start();            
}

private void InitializeCameras()
    {
        if (capture == null)
        {
            try
            {
                capture = new Capture(0);
            }
            catch // etc 
        }
    }

private void ProcessFrame(object sender, EventArgs arg)
    {
        image = capture.QueryFrame();
        image1.Source = BitmapSourceConvert.ToBitmapSource(image);
    }
}

public static class BitmapSourceConvert
{
   [DllImport("gdi32")]
    private static extern int DeleteObject(IntPtr o);

    public static BitmapSource ToBitmapSource(IImage image)
    {
        using (System.Drawing.Bitmap source = image.Bitmap)
        {
            IntPtr ptr = source.GetHbitmap(); //obtain the Hbitmap

            BitmapSource bs = System.Windows.Interop.Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHBitmap(
                ptr,
                IntPtr.Zero,
                Int32Rect.Empty,
                System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapSizeOptions.FromEmptyOptions());

            DeleteObject(ptr); //release the HBitmap
            return bs;
        }
    }
}
```

The following code is where I am up to but need help:

XAML (same as before)

```
<Window x:Class="EmguWPF_Test.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">

<Grid>
    <Image Height="215" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="62,66,0,0" Name="image1" Stretch="Fill" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="224"  />
</Grid>
</Window>
```

ViewModel Snippet (yes - perhaps too ambitious to be experimenting with design patterns):

```
public ViewModel()
    {    
        CaptureMethods.InitializeCameras();
        timer = new DispatcherTimer();
        timer.Tick += new EventHandler(CaptureMethods.ProcessFrame);
        timer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 10);
        timer.Start(); 
    }
```

CaptureMethods class, not working as a separate class in the way I want it to. You will notice I am now defining the capture field in this class, not in the ViewModel class:

```
class CaptureMethods
{
    private static Capture capture = null;

    public static void InitializeCameras()
    {
        if (capture == null)
        {
            try
            {
                capture = new Capture(0);
            }
            catch // etc 
        }
    }

public static void ProcessFrame(object sender, EventArgs arg)
    {
        image = capture.QueryFrame();
        image1.Source = BitmapSourceConvert.ToBitmapSource(image); // this is my problem line
    }
}

// BitmapSourceConvert class not repeated here to avoid duplication.
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion is not to use the WPF Image Box, but the Emgu's ImageBox (Emgu.CV.UI.ImageBox). It is a more complete control and it is designed to use with the framework.

The only problem is that type of control only works with Windows Forms, but you can always create a WinForms User Control with a Emgu's Image Box and use it in WPF inside a WindowsFormsHost.

Answer (score 2):

To expand a bit on [celsoap7's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16297523/575530) here is what the resulting XAML might look like:

```
<Window x:Class="WPFEmguCV.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:emui="clr-namespace:Emgu.CV.UI;assembly=Emgu.CV.UI"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="521" Width="1274">
    <Grid>
        <WindowsFormsHost>
            <emui:ImageBox x:Name="CapturedImageBox" Width="409" Height="353" />
        </WindowsFormsHost>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

I ([and others](http://www.emgu.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=1836)) found that marshaling the images onto the UI thread takes too much CPU and so you are better off doing as [celsoap7 suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16297523/575530) and put an EmguCV `ImageBox` inside a WPF `WindowsFormsHost`.

Sadly that may make the kind of MVVM binding you are asking about quite different from the structure you envisage.